# jQuery UI - .toogleClass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to **manipulate** `2 divs` on my page, basically when 1 `div` is hiden - in this example `div "template_class"` - another `div` expands to fill the gap, however at the moment "`template_class"` hides but nothing happens to another `div`, **why?**

**jQuery:**

```
  $( function() {
    $( ".toogle" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".template_class" ).toggleClass( "newClass", 1000 );
      $( "#content-link2").toggleClass( "newClass3", 1000);
    });
  } );
```

css:

```
.toogle{
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px;
    width: 160px;
    height:40px;
    top: 100px;
    background:#FF931E;
    z-index:15;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
}
.newClass3{
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 89%;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: right;
}
.newClass{
    top:0%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container template_class ">
    @foreach ($templates as $template)
    <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($template->file )}}">
        <img src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
        </a> @endforeach

</div>
    <div class="pace  pace-inactive">
    <div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pace-activity"></div>
</div>
<div class="features form-group">
    <input class="form-control filestyle margin images"  data-input="false" type="file" data-buttonText="Upload Logo" data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="readURL(this);" />

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  } );
  </script>
    <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary" id="showColor">Show Colors</button>
    <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary" id="hideColor">Hide Colors</button>
    <input title="Choose a color and then click on any box" style="display: none" class="btn btn-default form-control margin" type="color" id="colorChoice">
    <a style="display: none" href="#" class="btn btn-default form-control margin" id="cp4">Background</a>

    <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fonts1').bfhfonts({font: 'Arial'})" id="fontsShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Load Fonts</button>
    <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="fontsHide">Hide Fonts</button>
    <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="fonts1" class="form-control margin"></select>

    <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#googlefonts1').bfhgooglefonts({font: 'Lato'})" id="googleShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Google fonts</button>
    <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="googleHide">Hide Google</button>
    <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="googlefonts1" class="form-control margin"></select>

    <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fontsizes1').bfhfontsizes({fontsize: '12'})" id="sizeShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Load font size</button>
    <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="sizeHide">Hide font size</button>
    <select title="Choose a font size and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="fontsizes1" class="form-control margin"></select>

    <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="finishEdit">Done</button>
    <button class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="startEdit">Edit</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button onClick=" updateDatabase(this);" type="button" class="form-control margin btn btn-warning" id="getRequest">Save</button>
</div>
<div id="content-link2">
        <button class="form-control btn btn-success toogle" ></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Paste your HTML code please

Comment: I have pasted my html code

Comment: Yes it is duration

Comment: Can you fiddle your code ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: nope but you can check it here: https://www.webuilder.co.uk/template as you see div is closing but a div with black border doesn't extend to that empty space and button should be moving to the left as well so you can hide/show options so that users can have a bigger view of a div with border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i think you use the `.togleClass()` function wrongly. In your case, it is equal to `.toggleClass("classname", true)` which can only add the class to the element, not toggling it ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp)).

Other than that, i think your CSS is a bit of point. It's better to make it like this

```
.newClass{
    display: none;
}
```

As for the other divs, they should go up automatically. I don't know the initial style of the `#content-link2` , so clarification would help about why you need to make it float right etc.

Comment: after template_class is hidden content-link2 should get wider, if I don't float it ends up on left hand side of the page and half of the div cannot be seen as it is behind template_class

Comment: @Przemek but if you hide the template_class using my css, it won't be rendered at all and won't block the other div after the button got clicked. Can you make a fiddle to replicate your problem?

Comment: That's absolutely fine however if I press the button again, template_class doesn't show itself

Comment: @Przemek then try removing the second argument on the toggleClass function to just like this $(".template_class").toggleClass("newClass") and $("#content-link2").toggleClass("newClass3")

Comment: Okay, that looks better, is it possible to attach button to a div .template_class but when it's clicked make it not dissapear? Because at the moment it does dissapear along with button therefore it cannot be pressed again

Comment: @Przemek no, the button must be outside the div or it will disappear with the div. What you can do is change the div size to just show the button but i think that's for another question. (at least the toggleClass is now working)